# Installation of Tomcat8 (8.0.32-1ubuntu1.5) is failing

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

I run this command:

```
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tomcat8=8.0.32-1ubuntu1.5
```

This is failing with exeception:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Version '8.0.32-1ubuntu1.5' for 'tomcat8' was not found
```

The command was working before.
Was there a removal of this version?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your current repo is able to find requested package. Did you try to find package manually from https://tomcat.apache.org/ and install it?

Btw all archived versions: https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/

Comment: The strange is, that the command was working before the Weekend :-D.

Comment: try command: history | grep tomcat*

you will see all your command regarding to tomcat.. so maybe you did a tipo..

Comment: Thanks @PeterH for your help. The problem was not that the tomcat version ist removed, rather this was a problem with Docker. After deleting some older images and caches ---> the command was successful.